# Css alignment screwed

Tags: html, css

so the html code is at it follows

```
<ul class="tabs" data-persist="true">
    <li class="tab1"><a href="#view1">Dusk Drive</a></li>
    <li class="tab2"><a href="#view2">Imagini</a></li>
    <li class="tab3"><a href="#view3">Despre joc</a></li>
</ul>
```

the css is

```
/* Tab Content - menucool.com */

ul.tabs
{
    padding: 0px 0px;
    font-size: 0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left; /*set to left, center, or right to align the tabs as desired*/
}
        
ul.tabs li
{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right:0px; /*distance between tabs*/
}
        
ul.tabs li a
{
    font: normal 12px Verdana;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 16px;
    color: #000;
    /*background: url(images/tab_left.png) left no-repeat;*/
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
        
ul.tabs li a:visited
{
    color: #000;
}
        
ul.tabs li a:hover
{
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    /*background: url(images/tab_left.png) left no-repeat;*/
}
        
ul.tabs li.selected a, ul.tabs li.selected a:hover
{
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight:bold;
    /*background: url(images/tab_left.png) left no-repeat;*/
}
        
        
ul.tabs li.selected a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.tabcontents
{
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

li.tab1 {
    float: left;
    background-image: url("images/tab_left.png");
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-color: #33cccc;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

li.tab2 {
    float: left;
    background-image: url("images/tab_left1.png");
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-color: #33cccc;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

li.tab3 {
    background-image: url("images/tab_left2.png");
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}


#view1 {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #33cccc;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#view2 {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ccffcc;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#view3 {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

it produces a graphics as
[image]

instead of

[image]

just with the yellow background of "Despre joc" that's what's messed up

i just can't figure it out on how to align it as the other two's

Comment: Provide a link to JSFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `clear:both` after list tabs

```
<div class="clear"></div>

.clear {
   clear:both;
}
```

Comment: the same result the third tab is miss aligned

Comment: you need to add this after ul is closed

Answer (score 0):

Edit your css .

```
li.tab3 {
float: left;
background-image: url("images/tab_left1.png");
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-color: #ffffcc;
border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
```

}